# PostgreSQL database is not exposed to the port I expect in docker-compose

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, express, microservices

I am trying to set up multiservices architecture in my Node.js backend with docker. I have currently two services with two separate databases

```sh
version: "3"
services:
  server-api-getaway:
    build:
      context: "."
      dockerfile: "./server-api-gateway/Dockerfile"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    ports:
      - "7100:7100"
    volumes:
      - ./server-api-gateway:/usr/src/app/server-api-gateway
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      - REDIS_URL=redis://cache
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@db:3336/dbname
      - DATABASE_PORT=3336
      - DATABASE_HOST=host.docker.internal
      - POSTGRES_DB=dbname
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - PORT=7100

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=dbname
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - "3336:3306"

  server-user-service:
    build:
      context: "."
      dockerfile: "./server-user-service/Dockerfile"
    depends_on:
      - user-service-db
    ports:
      - "7000:7000"
    volumes:
      - ./server-user-service:/usr/src/app/server-user-service
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
      - REDIS_URL=redis://cache
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@user-service-db:3307/dbname
      - DATABASE_PORT=3307
      - DATABASE_HOST=host.docker.internal
      - POSTGRES_DB=dbname
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - PORT=7000

  user-service-db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=dbname
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"

  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: cache
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

volumes:
  pgdata:
    driver: local
  pgconf:
    driver: local
  pglog:
    driver: local
```

I expect both databases to run on different ports, but when I run *docker-compose up* they are exposed to *5432* port

> 2021-03-05 07:12:10.111 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address
> "0.0.0.0", port 5432

When I connect my service to port *5432* everything works fine. But I need two databases to be exposed to different ports. How can I achieve it?

*Update*

I've changed port mapping as was suggested in comments.

```
  user-service-db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=dbname
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:3336"
```

And made a fresh start after *docker-compose down*

Result remained the same

> user-service-db_1      | 2021-03-05 10:01:23.023 UTC [1] LOG:
> listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432

probably there is a detail I am missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an implementation detail, containers have their own private IP addresses.  You can't usually access these addresses from outside Docker, but when your container tries to connect to the host name `db`, that maps to one of these internal addresses.  This means that it's okay for processes in different containers to listen on the same port, since each process is in its own isolated network space.

That means it's standard for a packaged process to listen on its "normal" port.  The output you're seeing is the output of the PostgreSQL startup; this will *always* listen on 0.0.0.0:5432 (unless you make tricky modifications to its configuration file).

Connections between containers also always connect to the "normal" port:

```yaml
 # Use ordinary port, ports: are ignored       vvvv
- DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/dbname
```

Publishing a port makes it accessible from outside Docker, using the host's IP address (and DNS name).  The second `ports:` number needs to match the port number inside the container, the first one can be anything that's not already in use.  Connections between containers never use this.

```yaml
ports:
  #       vvvv the ordinary port, fixed by the image
  - "3336:5432"
```

"Expose" as a verb means almost nothing in modern Docker.  `EXPOSE` in a Dockerfile is mostly documentation and there's no reason to use the Compose `expose:` setting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose the correct port.
Postgres default port is `5432`: i.e. the postgres service in your docker container will listen to port `5432`.
I guess, on the host, you want to listen `3336` (or `3306`?).

in this case the mapping must be:

```yml
ports:
  - "3336:5432"
```

i.e. the format is `HOST:CONTAINER`

see also:

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports
- https://www.whitesourcesoftware.com/free-developer-tools/blog/docker-expose-port/

Comment: Thank you for the links I will read. I've changed port mapping as you suggested, but the result is the same. I did docker-compose down and even deleted image to start from skratch. I will update my question.

Comment: oh - sorry, I think I' have swapped the ports: should be `3336:5432`: I'll update the answer.